# get specific word from a seperated statement by a comma?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this string and for example i need to get the the word **green eyes** from specific string that is sperated by a comma like this example

```
young lady , beautiful , green eyes , wearing shirt , wearing necklace
```

I want to get for example green eyes using the word **eyes** for example

how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the string, then filter trough the array to find the words that match

```js
const str = "young lady,beautiful,green eyes,wearing shirt,wearing necklace";

const findWord = (word) => str.split(",").filter(x => x.includes(word))

console.log(findWord("green"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split those phrases by comma separator using `arr.split(',')` method.

Then using `arr.filter` method you can filter array items by given condition.

```
const input = 'young lady , beautiful , green eyes , wearing shirt , wearing necklace';
const query = 'eyes';

const phrases = input.split(',');
const filteredPhrases = phrases.filter(phrase => phrase.includes(query));

console.log(filteredPhrases); // output: [ " green eyes " ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a function version answer.

```js
const string =
  "young lady , beautiful , green eyes , wearing shirt , wearing necklace";

const getSpecificWord = (string, word) => {
  let selectedItem = string.split(",").find((s) => s.includes(word));
  return selectedItem;
};

const result = getSpecificWord(string, "eye");

console.log(result)
```